# How to visit pre-defined URLs from file

Tags: cypress

If I have 30 pages to check, for example, EN has a disclaimer, but other 29 language don't, what would be the best way to do this? For example, right now I have it like this:

```js
const urls = ['http://google.com/en',
  'http://google.com/bg'
]

describe('Disclaimer check', () => {
  urls.forEach((url) => {
    it(`Checks disclaimer text ${url}`, () => {
      cy.visit(url)
      cy.get('.Disclaimer').should('be.visible')
        .and('contain', 'This is disclaimer.')
    })
  })
})
```

For 2 sites it's fine to define them in the same code but other file that checks that Disclaimer isn't there would be 29 different URL-s. What would be the best practice here? One idea is to separate all the test but that would mean 30 tests for each feature which doesn't sound too great.

As url I'm working with uses many different values in it, making it short with baseurl doesn't seem to fit also.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know exactly which URL's will have the Disclaimer and which ones will not have it?

Comment: Yes, all markets and URL-s have been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding all of your data to a data object, import that data object, and then using [Cypress Lodash](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/_) to iterate a number of times should achieve your goal.

```js
// data.js
// defining data
export const data =[{
  "url": "www.google.com",
  "hasDisclaimer": true
}, {
  "url": "www.other-url.com",
  "hasDisclaimer": false
}...
]
```

You can then wrap the returned array and use it in a Cypress chain.

```js
import { data } from './path/to/data'

describe('Tests', () => {
  Cypress._.times(data.length, (index) => {
    const curr = data[index];
    it(`Checks disclaimer text ${curr.url}`, () => {
      cy.visit(curr.url).then(() => {
        if (curr.hasDisclaimer) {
          cy.get('.Disclaimer').should('be.visible')
          .and('contain', 'This is disclaimer.');
        } else {
          // code for checking disclaimer does not exist
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right path. This will be a good case for using [cypress-each](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-each). Cypress-each will run all tests regardless if one or more fail. Depending on how long it takes, you may want to break down the `it.each` test into another file.

```
import 'cypress-each' // can included in /support/index.js

describe('Disclaimer check', () => {

  // baseUrl: http://google.com
  const noDisclaimerUrl = [
    '/bg',
    // all other languages
  ]

  it('/en does have disclaimer text', () => {
    cy.visit('/en')
    // test code
  }) 

  it.each((noDisclaimerUrl)
     `%s does not have disclaimer text`
     (url) => {
       cy.visit(url)
       // test code
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Under your Fixtures folder create a `urls.json` file like this:

```js
[
    "https://google.com/en",
    "https://google.com/bg",
    "https://url3.com",
    "https://url4.com"
]
```

Now assuming that you know which URLs don't have the disclaimer, you can simply add them in the `If` condition and apply the `not.exist` assertion.

```js
import urls from '../fixtures/urls.json'

describe('Disclaimer check', () => {
  urls.forEach((url) => {
    it(`Checks disclaimer text ${url}`, () => {
      cy.visit(url)
      if (url == 'https://google.com/en' || url == 'https://url3.com') {
        //Check for URL's where disclaimer doesn't exist
        cy.get('.Disclaimer').should('not.exist')
      } else {
        //Check for URL's where disclaimer exists
        cy.get('.Disclaimer')
          .should('be.visible')
          .and('contain', 'This is disclaimer.')
      }
    })
  })
})
```